# maxWidth is not applied in Next.js Image component

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

```
<Image src="/assets/blog/image.webp" style={{ maxWidth: "700px" }} width={1400} height={1400} />
```

**Error**

Image with src /assets/blog/image.webp is assigned the following styles, which are overwritten by automatically-generated styles: maxWidth

I just build the app and test. maxWidth is working on the build production but not working on run on localhost. Why?

Comment: Could you show the code of the Image component if you made one urself?

Comment: Code is already in Ques. (Image component)

Comment: I am asking for the code of the Image component basically the Image function component code. Where u defined Image like this: `const Image = () => {}` or `class Image extends React.Component {}`

Comment: I am using NextJS, so there is no function like that. It is already predefined in nextjs. I just import in from next/image

Answer (score 2):

Add a wrapper div

```
// you could set the height here to and image will contain thi size
<div style={{ maxWidth: "700px" }} >
  <Image src={path} layout="fill" className={'image'} />
</div>
```

css for 'image'

```
.image {
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100% !important;
    position: relative !important;
    height: unset !important;
  }
```